# Coupled Differential Equation in Polar Coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following two coupled differential equations:

$$E = \frac{1}{2}V^{2} - \frac{GM}{R} + \frac{3}{8}\left(1 - 3\nu \right)\frac{V^{4}}{c^{2}} + \frac{GM}{2Rc^{2}}\left( \left(3 + \nu \right)V^{2} + \nu \left(\mathbf{N} \mathbf{V} \right)^{2} - \frac{GM}{R} \right)$$

$$\mathbf{J} = \mu \left(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{V} \right) \Bigg[ 1 + \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - 3 \nu \right) \frac{V^{2}}{c^{2}} + \left(3 + \nu \right)\frac{GM}{Rc^{2}} \Bigg] \, .$$
where $\mathbf{N} = \mathbf{R}/|\mathbf{R}|$

Given polar coordinates one may write:

$$V^{2} = \dot{R}^2 + R^2\dot{\theta}^2 \, , $$ one can rewrite the above equations as:

$$E = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{R}^2 + R^2\dot{\theta}^2)^{2} - \frac{GM}{R} + \frac{3}{8}\left(1 - 3\nu \right)\frac{(\dot{R}^2 + R^2\dot{\theta}^2)^{4}}{c^{2}} + \frac{GM}{2Rc^{2}}\left( \left(3 + \nu \right)(\dot{R}^2 + R^2\dot{\theta}^2)^{2} + \nu \left(\dot{R} \right)^{2} - \frac{GM}{R} \right)$$

$$\mathbf{J} = \mu \left(R^2\dot{\theta}^2 \right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - 3 \nu \right) \frac{(\dot{R}^2 + R^2\dot{\theta}^2)^{2}}{c^{2}} + \left(3 + \nu \right)\frac{GM}{Rc^{2}} \right) \, .$$

Dropping $c^{-4}$ terms how can I express the above equations as:

$$\dot{R}^{2} = A + \frac{2B}{R} + \frac{C}{R^{2}} + \frac{D}{R^{3}}$$
$$\dot{\theta} = \frac{H}{R^{2}} + \frac{I}{R^{3}}$$